# Explode from html tags in php

Tags: php, joomla2.5, explode, virtuemart

i want to get the order number from below string.

```
$str = '<table class="adminlist">
<tbody><tr>
<td>Payment Name</td>
 <td align="left"><span class="vmpayment_name">Aurthorize.net</span><span class="vmpayment_description">New payment gateway</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Order number</td>
 <td align="left">9b27041</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Amount</td>
 <td align="left">51.30 USD</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Transaction ID</td>
 <td align="left">2200484213</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>';
```

How i explode in php. I have tried but not explode . I want order number from above string like

> 9b27041

And main thing is that all the values is dynamic :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  xpath is a good way to extract the value. For this I assume that the position of the order number row is allways the same. The code below does the trick for me.

```
     <?php
$str = '<table class="adminlist">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>Payment Name</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="vmpayment_name">Aurthorize.net</span><span class="vmpayment_description">New payment gateway</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Order number</td>
        <td align="left">9b27041</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td align="left">51.30 USD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Transaction ID</td>
        <td align="left">2200484213</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>';


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//tr[2]/td[2]");

$node = $nodes->item(0);
echo $node->textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost impossible to do, PHP cant know where the Order number begins. Try jQuery, give the  the class="order_nr" and you can access it easiely.

Only possibility in PHP would be to use strip_tags($str) and then look how to get the order nr from the remaining string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "PHP Simple HTML DOM parser" its great solution for problems like that, you can read more about it here http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/